# Tidyverse not loading after downloading the package in Rstudio

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here's the error it's showing.

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
> .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
> call: NULL
> error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> there is no package called ‘colorspace’

I tried downloading the package again but its still not loading, please provide me with a solution, i'm completely new to R/Rstudio.

Comment: Have you installed the `colorspace` package?

Answer (score 1):

That error says that `colorspace` package is missing. You can install it by running:

`install.packages("colorspace")`

Alternatively, in RStudio go to Tools -> Install packages, type `colorspace` in the *Packages* field and click *Install* (with *Install dependencies* checked).

After `colorspace` package is installed, restart and try loading `tidyverse` again.